# How I can retrieve geolocation info for an IP Address in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ip-address

I have a table in BigQuery containing my customers' IP addresses, and I want to understand their geographical distribution.

Is there any way I can retrieve geolocation information for these IP addresses, like city, state, and country using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a post about doing it efficiently using Geolite2 in GCP blog:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds/

The query used Felipe `fh-bigquery` dataset, that you'll need to recreate using Geolite2 source.

Comment: Nice approach! I'll test it out and accept this as an answer since it is faster and more cost-efficient than using remote functions.

Comment: After some testing, I indeed find it very efficient. Since it was not very straightforward I prepared this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/justdataplease/bigquery-ipaddresses) on how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve geolocation information for an IP Address or identify its physical location you need to use a Geolocation database.

There is a service called [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/) that provides a free/lite version of the Geolocation database, that you can use.

You can then write a function in Python to use this database and retrieve the geolocation information like city state and country for the specified IP.

In a recent release, BigQuery [announced the support of Remote Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/extending-bigquery-functions) that can be used to wrap Python functions into a SQL function that can be used in your queries.

You can find the full code on how to achieve that in this [GitHub](https://github.com/justdataplease/bigquery-iplookup) repo.

Comment: There is also a native Bigquery approach (accepted answer) to achieve the desired result that is less straightforward but faster and more cost-efficient.

Comment: Please don't answer questions only to promote your blog

Comment: I did not intend to promote my blog, if you read the accepted answer and the comment I am sure you will understand that. This is an actual question I had and wanted others to find it too. Do you propose to copy-paste the whole tutorial here or not write it at all? I am new here so I do not know exactly the correct way contribute, please enlighten me.